# Inequality and percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In the electoral process of an association, the members voted among 27 candidates to select the president. Each voter voted one candidate (and the candidates did not have the right to vote). After the polls close and the votes counting, it turned out that the percentage that each candidate got was less than 1 unit at minimum from the number of votes this candidate got (for example, he got 2.8% and 4 votes). How many members voted at minimum?

OK this is an easy one but I am stuck:
Let n be the number of voters and A1, A2,..., A27 the number of votes that each of the 27 candidates got.

Obviously A1+A2+...+A27=n
The percentages are:
100*A1/n, 100*A2/n etc.
We also have that:

A1-100*A1/n>=1
A2-100*A2/n>=1
...
A27-100*A27/n>=1

By adding:
n-100n/n>=27 so n>=127.

but it doesn't work for any number of votes, for example if someone got 1 vote, the percentage is about 1% so we do not have a difference of 1.
I think we must take the floor of the number. Any ideas?

Comment: So, if someone gets 0 votes, what must be his percentage? -1%??